# Can we connect mobile to reverse cam display output

Tags: wiring, camera, backup-camera

My cars reverse camera's display break. I can see a mini USB cable was connected to the display. Can I connect my mobile phone to that output using mini USB female to micro USB male jack with any kind of USB streaming app?

Comment: So for the display that was an output or do you think it was an input? Then, can you actually send the data format the display expects? ie what was the output of the camera?

Answer (score 1):

What are the outputs from the camera? 
You could try something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008I679QG) (from [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100427/use-an-android-phone-as-a-monitor-screen-with-av-in-wire) question) and see if that'd work with an OTG cable. **I can't guarantee that it'll work**, but it seem like a really fun project to do imo.

However, buying a new screen might be the same price as there are tons on Amazon/Chinese websites

**Edit**

Are you sure the micro USB input to the display, was not just the power instead of actual video

**Completely off topic**

You can also get a Raspberry Pi / Arduino, accept video signal from camera, plug in a wi-fi dongle, connect with your phone to the IP (within the same network, so make sure you use your Pi/Arduino to host, rather than receive) and stream the video.

Pretty sure you'll have (lots) of delay. So be careful and don't hit anything behind you...

Comment: The display was connected to a micro USB port. The micro USB provided power as well as data to the screen. At this moment I just need only a screen. That screen is not available in the market. So I have to buy an entire module once again. So I think about my old mobile as a display. I can see some mini USB to micro USB converters in the market. But don't know if it will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

reverse cameras are almost certainly analog signals.  That's probably the power cord for it.  However if you have an android-based deck, it's possible that it COULD actually be the camera.  There are a couple of external av adapters that hook up that way.  I have one myself.  usb-otg -> digital input device -> camera.  People use them a lot when doing heads-up flying of drones but they are also designed for reverse cameras (you can flip the image).  In Summary, follow that cable and it may lead to a device with a standard av input.